# Dynamic Pivot Tables MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to create a dynamic pivot table to get results in different columns rather than rows.

This is the table I'm using to test

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors](
[Client_Id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Project_Id] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Person_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Author_Number] [int] NOT NULL,
[Family_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[First_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
VALUES ('TEST','TEST',12345,1,'Giust','Fede')
INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
VALUES ('TEST','TEST',12345,2,'Giust','Fede')
INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
VALUES ('TEST','TEST',12346,1,'Giust','Fede')
INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
VALUES ('TEST','TEST',12346,2,'Giust','Fede')
INSERT INTO Authors (Client_Id, Project_Id, Person_Id, Author_Number, Family_Name, First_Name)
VALUES ('TEST','TEST',12346,3,'Giust','Fede')
```

So far I get the results like this

```
CLIENT_ID   PROJECT_ID  PERSON_ID   AUTHOR_NUMBER   FAMILY_NAME FIRST_NAME
TEST        TEST        12345       1               Giust       Fede
TEST        TEST        12345       2               Ma          Ke
TEST        TEST        12346       1               Jones       Peter
TEST        TEST        12346       2               Davies      Bob
TEST        TEST        12346       3               Richards        Craig
```

I need the results to come out like this, and to be dynamic because sometime I can have 2 authors, or 10 authors.

```
CLIENT_ID   PROJECT_ID  PERSON_ID   FAMILY_NAME_1   FIRST_NAME_1    FAMILY_NAME_2   FIRST_NAME_2        FAMILY_NAME_3   FIRST_NAME_3      
TEST        TEST        12345       Giust           Fede            Ma              Ke

TEST        TEST        12346       Jones           Peter           Davies          Bob                 Richards            Craig
```

I've been trying to use this code, but keep getting errors

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cadd/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few suggestions to solve your issue.

First, your current code is unpivoting all of the columns in the table, you only need to UNPIVOT the `Family_Name` and `First_Name` columns.  As a result I would not use a variable to get this list of columns, just hard-code the two columns you need to unpivot.

Then to get the list of columns to PIVOT, alter the code to use both the `Author_number` and then a string with the column names `Family_Name` and `First_Name`:

```
select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col + '_'+cast(Author_Number as varchar(10))) 
                    from Authors
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'Family_Name' col, 1 so union all
                      select 'First_Name', 2
                    ) c
                    group by col, author_number, so
                    order by author_number, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

This gives a list of cols:

```
|                                                                                     COLUMN_0 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| [Family_Name_1],[First_Name_1],[Family_Name_2],[First_Name_2],[Family_Name_3],[First_Name_3] |
```

Making these changes to your code the final query will be

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col + '_'+cast(Author_Number as varchar(10))) 
                    from Authors
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'Family_Name' col, 1 so union all
                      select 'First_Name', 2
                    ) c
                    group by col, author_number, so
                    order by author_number, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select Client_id, Project_id, Person_Id, '+@colsPivot+' 
      from
      (
        select Client_id, Project_id, Person_Id, 
          col+''_''+cast(Author_Number as varchar(10)) col, val
        from
        (
          select Client_id, Project_id,
            Person_Id, 
            Author_Number, 
            Family_Name, 
            First_Name
          from Authors
        ) s
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in (Family_Name, First_Name)
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for col in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cadd/29). This gives a result:

```
| CLIENT_ID | PROJECT_ID | PERSON_ID | FAMILY_NAME_1 | FIRST_NAME_1 | FAMILY_NAME_2 | FIRST_NAME_2 | FAMILY_NAME_3 | FIRST_NAME_3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      TEST |       TEST |     12345 |         Giust |         Fede |            Ma |           Ke |        (null) |       (null) |
|      TEST |       TEST |     12346 |         Jones |        Peter |        Davies |          Bob |      Richards |        Craig |
```

Comment: Looks very promising! Thanks so much for such a quick reply! I'll test on our server and see if the results we get are useful. I only pasted a few columns in the example but the source table about 30 columns.

Comment: How can I make this into a function or view? Is that possible?

Comment: @FedericoGiust Since you are using dynamic SQL it must be in a stored procedure. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in views or functions.

Comment: Is there a way to do similar thing but on a view or function so I can do JOINS in the future with some other table?

Comment: @FedericoGiust Do you have a limited number of `author_numbers` that are allowed? Or is it unlimited?

Comment: @FedericoGiust Then you have to use dynamic sql to pivot the data.